# Can't create Folder automatically with camel

Tags: java

[Here's what I got](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8MmHz.png)

I'm pretty sure I followed all the steps correctly by the instructor, can someone point me in right direction? The objective is to create a camel route. One that creates one "files" folder and "input" folder. when I add files on folder input another one (output) should be created to store the files, but the files folder doesnt even get to be created to beggin with. Please help

Comment: You'll like get responses if you do not paste images of code.  Here is why: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557/1847378